# Try running composer in git bash and composer not found

Tags: composer-php

Most of the time I run composer using git bash and using laptop, now using desktop and I try to run composer using git bash again, it show

> bash: composer: command not found

Does anyone has the same problem with me?

Comment: in this new computer, do you have (a) in your composer directory the .phar, .bat and no-extension composer files, and (b) this directory configured in your PATH?